# Write the text that is between h1 tags

Tags: php, jquery, html, tags, title

How can we take in PHP or jQuery that is written between the `<h2> </h2>` of each page to put the title of my pages so that each page is different.
 
Example:

```
<section class="sub_header">
    <h2>Contact</h2>
    <h5>Contactez-nous !</h5>
</section>

=> <title>Contact</title>
```

It's possible ?

 PHP, jQuery load() function...?

Thanks

My soluce:
I answer because it could be used for some.

I'll add this little code on important pages. using the superglobal 'REQUEST_URI':

```
<?php 
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == '/index_contact.html') {
$data = 'Contact'; 

}elseif(
$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == '/index_blog.html') {
$data = 'The blog'; 

}else{
$data = 'Default title.'; 
} 
// Display the name of the page if data exists
if (isset($data)) {echo $data;} ?>
```

Hoping that it will be useful for some.

Comment: I edit... Sorry this is not the same

Answer (score 0):

You can try with prag_match to extract data between h1 tag.

```
$data ="Your content goes here";
preg_match('/<h2>(.*?)<\/h2>/s', $data, $matches);
echo $matches[1];
exit;
```

Comment: Hey sorry Ram, i have edited my answer :/

Comment: content already exists on all my pages this may make me a lot of work. There's no easier way?